# Populate ListView based on Spinner Selection

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, spinner

I'm wondering how I can populate my ListView based on what is selected on a spinner.

I have a spinner populated with a string array from strings.xml as follows:

```
<string-array name="genres">
    <item>Action</item>
    <item>Adventure</item>
    <item>Animation</item>
    <item>Comedy</item>
    <item>Crime</item>
    <item>Drama</item>
    <item>Horror</item>
    <item>Science Fiction</item>
    <item>Thriller</item>
    <item>Western</item>
</string-array>
```

I have other arrays created, and depending on the movie genre that is selected, I want to populate a listview with these arrays:

```
<string-array name="actionMovie">
    <item>Die Hard</item>
    <item>The Dark Knight</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="adventureMovie">
    <item>The Goonies</item>
    <item>Back to the Future</item>
</string-array>
```

I'm not really sure how to proceed with this. Here are some snippets of what I have in my main activity.

```
Spinner spinGenre;
ListView lstViewMovies;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
spinGenre = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerGenre);
lstViewMovies = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewMovies);
```

I used setOnItemSelectedListener to retrieve the value that was selected in this spinner. Just for testing, I am using toast messages display what value is selected in the spinner, but that is not functioning correctly. This is how my onItemSelected method currently looks, could someone point me in the right direction to making the toasts work (for testing purposes), or even show me how I can get the ListView to populate with the correct string array?

```
spinGenre.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            if (item.toString() == "Action") {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Action Genre Selected!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (item.toString() == "Adventure") {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Adventure Genre Selected!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (item.toString() == "Animation") {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Aanimation Genre Selected!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (item.toString() == "Comedy") {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Comedy Genre Selected!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (item.toString() == "Crime") {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Crime Genre Selected!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (item.toString() == "Drama") {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Drama Genre Selected!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (item.toString() == "Horror") {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Horror Genre Selected!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (item.toString() == "Science Fiction") {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Science Fiction Genre Selected!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (item.toString() == "Thriller") {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Thriller Genre Selected!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (item.toString() == "Western") {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Western Genre Selected!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please select another genre!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own issue, just thought I would post here to help anyone out.

My string arrays stayed the same as in my question (located in strings.xml).

In my onCreate methods I added the following: 
call for listeners:

```
spinGenre.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
lstViewMovies.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

I then populated string arrays using what I had in my strings.xml file:

```
String [] action;
String [] adventure;
String [] animation;
String [] comedy;
String [] crime;
String [] drama;
String [] horror;
String [] scifi;
String [] thriller;
String [] western;

action = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.actionMovie);
adventure = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.adventureMovie);
animation = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.animationMovie);
comedy = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.comedyMovie);
crime = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.crimeMovie);
drama = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.dramaMovie);
horror = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.horrorMovie);
scifi = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.scienceFictionMovie);
thriller = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.thrillerMovie);
western = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.westernMovie);
```

That is the end of my onCreate. My new onItemSelected method looks like this, and it will populate the listview with the required array from the strings.xml file.

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

    if (item.compareToIgnoreCase("Action") == 0) {
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, action);
        lstViewMovies.setAdapter(adapter);
    } else if (item.compareToIgnoreCase("Adventure") == 0) {
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, adventure);
        lstViewMovies.setAdapter(adapter);
    } else if (item.compareToIgnoreCase("Animation") == 0) {
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, animation);
        lstViewMovies.setAdapter(adapter);
    } else if (item.compareToIgnoreCase("Comedy") == 0) {
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, comedy);
        lstViewMovies.setAdapter(adapter);
    } else if (item.compareToIgnoreCase("Crime") == 0) {
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, crime);
        lstViewMovies.setAdapter(adapter);
    } else if (item.compareToIgnoreCase("Drama") == 0) {
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, drama);
        lstViewMovies.setAdapter(adapter);
    } else if (item.compareToIgnoreCase("Horror") == 0) {
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, horror);
        lstViewMovies.setAdapter(adapter);
    } else if (item.compareToIgnoreCase("Science Fiction") == 0) {
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, scifi);
        lstViewMovies.setAdapter(adapter);
    } else if (item.compareToIgnoreCase("Thriller") == 0) {
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, thriller);
        lstViewMovies.setAdapter(adapter);
    } else if (item.compareToIgnoreCase("Western") == 0) {
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, western);
        lstViewMovies.setAdapter(adapter);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please select another genre!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

//auto generated method with onItemSelected method - unused
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
```

This works as I needed it to! It may not be the best option, but as a new programmer, this is working for me. If you have a better way of doing it, please let me know. I would love to learn more!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setOnItemSelectedListener()` method on spinner to get callback of which position is selected. On the basis of position, you can populate listview.

Comment: Thanks. I added a setOnItemSelectedListener in the onCreate method. I populated it with toast messages so I can test to make sure the spinner is being selected properly. It's not though. It's not picking up my If statements, it just executes the else. I updated my question with this, any suggestions?